# How to ignore the automatic page breaks?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am using Excel Interop to create a report.

I am trying to programatically set the page breaks. I've been successful in doing so by using:

```
        this.ActiveWorksheet.HPageBreaks.Add(this[row + 1, 9].Range);
        this.ActiveWorksheet.VPageBreaks.Add(this[row + 1, 8].Range);
```

(the this[row...col] code refers to our base Excel generator but ultimately refers to a range with a given column / row).

When the report generates I can see my manually added page breaks; however the automatic page breaks still show up and they're in the wrong places so ultimately this makes my code useless. I need to make use of only my page breaks and ignore the automatic ones.

Is it possible to do so?

I've tried resetting the page breaks to no avail. I've also tried setting the FitToPagesWide property on the worksheet page setup property with no luck.

Comment: That's very strange. Using the same code as you, Excel set my page breaks as requested and only began the automatic ones beyond the manual ones (i.e. there were no automatic ones inside the ranges covered by the manual ones). What version of Excel are you using? Perhaps seeing some more of your code might help.

Comment: How strange. My code literally shoves data cell by cell into the Excel workbook - nothing special other than setting a ranges values and then I call those lines where necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting

`PageSetup.Zoom = false;`

before setting FitToPagesWide = 1

It appears that unless you explicitly set zoom to false, the FitToPagesWide/Tall properties are ignored.